# pressing F5 and launching in browser does nothing

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

I'm new to ASP.Net. I have opened a solution which builds with no errors. When I press `F5`, a new tab is opened in my Chrome window with the URL `http://localhost:4435/foo/Default.aspx`. However, nothing happens -- no page is displayed. It just appears to be loading forever.

When I try to access the page without going through Studio, using a URL that looks like this: `http://localhost/solution-name/trunk/foo/`, I get the following error:

```
Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error: 


Line 253:      </controls>
Line 254:    </pages>
Line 255:    <roleManager enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true" defaultProvider="AspNetSqlRoleProvider">
Line 256:      <providers>
Line 257:        <clear/>
```

I'm not sure if the 2 are related. I just want to get this solution up and running. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 different issues here.

The first (pressing F5 to start) is quite probably due to something in the `global.asax` (if it exists) or the `default.aspx` page itself spinning off into nowhere land.  Usually a bad configuration of a database connection whose timeout is way too long (like 5 minutes).

The second issue boils down to that location not being the root directory for the application and is a configuration issue.

What I'd do is first look at the database connection strings, generally located in your web.config, and see if they are valid.

Comment: I went into `web.config` and see 2 entries in `<connectionStrings>` tag. I haven't set up any DB for this solution, so it's possible that this may be the cause of my "F5" problem. Is MS SQL Server Management Studio the right tool for fixing this? I assume I need to locate a copy of the database and copy it in my local machine, then I'll create a user with the credentials I see in web.config. Am I on the right track?

Comment: "that location not being the root directory for the application and is a configuration issue." <-- where do I go to resolve this problem?

Comment: @snoopy76: on the location thing, set up IIS to point to that location as a website on a particular port number.  Don't depend on cassini (VS's built in web server) to still be running when you aren't in debug mode.

Comment: @snoopy76:  On the connection strings: that's hard to tell.  Have you tried putting break points in the page_load method of the page you are trying to load and step through whatever it is trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You showed 2 different URLS... one with a port number (localhost : 4435) and another without it.

The first one (with port number) is normally been handle by IIS Express or the integrated Visual Studio web server (that depends on your project configuration) and the second url (without port) is been handled by your local IIS.

So... You definitely have 2 different issues.

**About your first issue:**

If your project is using IIS Express, I would recommend your to check the configuration and log files (look at the folder %userprofile%\documents\IISExpress)

**Second issue:**

Open IIS Manager and make sure "solution-name" is marked as Application.

Hope it helps.